# Cucumber report creation crashes for results merge via Jenkins Cucumber Report plugin

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, jenkins-plugins, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

The Cucumber reports plugin (version 5.7.3) for Jenkins (version 2.346.3) crashed when parsing a unique JSON file of full campaign but works fine for a single scenario.

Backtrace is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You are not able to use this type of results merge. The start_timestamp field should be part of element object. Please, update the cucumber-jvm version.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:145)
    at net.masterthought.cucumber.reducers.ReportFeatureWithRetestMerger.updateElements(ReportFeatureWithRetestMerger.java:53)
    at net.masterthought.cucumber.reducers.ReportFeatureWithRetestMerger.merge(ReportFeatureWithRetestMerger.java:34)
    at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportResult.<init>(ReportResult.java:46)
    at net.masterthought.cucumber.ReportBuilder.generateReports(ReportBuilder.java:98)
    at net.masterthought.jenkins.CucumberReportPublisher.generateReport(CucumberReportPublisher.java:563)
    at net.masterthought.jenkins.CucumberReportPublisher.perform(CucumberReportPublisher.java:434)
    at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:79)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:816)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:765)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:179)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:709)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1922)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
```

I cannot share the JSON file so how could I debug this crash? Thank you for your idea.

Best regards

Comment: Please provide cucumber java version, pom.xml detailing cucumber report generation and any mrthods/classes that are responsible for the results merge.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for interest. OS version is ```Ubuntu 20.04.4```, java version on node where the tests are executed is ```openjdk 17.0.4 2022-07-19```; and ```openjdk 11.06.16 2022-07-19``` on jenkins. I do not know which pom.xml or methods/classes that generate the merge results, I just configured post-build cucumber reports publishing in a Jenkins free-style job.

Comment: Ok, please provide the configuration you have applied for the Cucumber reports plugin by editing the original question, so we can ascertain from there.